# Using variables from for loop after loop has closed

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, while-loop

I have deleted the old question in hopes this simplified and more precise version will work.

I have a file:

```
#Works Command
cd /tmp
mkdir folder
echo "it worked" >file
cat file

#Not working Command
cd /tmp
mkdir file
echo "it didn't work" >wrong
cat wrong
```

There can be as few as 1 grouping of commands and as many as 20 groupings, but each grouping of commands is prefixed with a comment that ends in "Command"

What I am hoping to accomplish is set each comment as a variable that when called will execute the commands.

Desired result if I echo $var1

```
cd /tmp
mkdir folder
echo "it worked" >file
cat file
```

I have tried using:

```
while read -r line; do var+=("$line"); done < <(awk '/Command/,/Command/' file)
```

To set the comments to variables, but I have not found a viable solution for the groupings of commands.

I have tried using:

```
for i in {1..5}
do
awk '/'"${var[$i]}"'/,/'"${var[$i+1]}"'/' file |egrep -vi "${var[$i]}|${var[$i+1]}"
done
```

Hopefully that will help clarify things. my apologies for posting a question without a clear desire of what needs to be done.

Comment: Code don't match outputs!

Comment: `$var[$i+1]`  is empty if `i`point to last block.!

Comment: You say that (if I'm understanding correctly, anyway) `${var[2]}` expands to `cat bunny fish`, yet the word `bunny` does not appear at all in your sample input. We'll have a hard time determining what you are trying to do without examples that are actually feasible. Consider reworking your example input and output so that they are actually consistent...

Comment: Have you posted your _desired_ output? If not, could you do so?

Comment: Sorry! I have corrected the input and posted the desired output. Thanks!

Comment: When I see a question about "exporting variables" in shell, I expect it to be about scope and environment management. This has nothing to do with the topic at all, as best I can tell. Perhaps it might be better to try to find a title that avoids using terms of the art for other than their technical meaning?

Comment: I have corrected the title to a more precise(?) question. I'm not actually looking to manipulate the text, but to set certain parts of the file to be variables. There can be more or less grouping than the example i listed. Also the first line of each grouping can vary but it will always include "fish" Basically what I am hoping to be able to do is set "cat elk fish" to a variable that when called will execute the remaining lines in the grouping.

Comment: With the new title, this sounds like an exact fit for BashFAQ #24: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024; that said, from a quick scan of the body text, it isn't clear to me how that title relates. A more effectively minimized question (see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help with clarity in the future.

Comment: ...if your real underlying problem _is_ FAQ #24, then this is very much a duplicate of something asked and answered many, many times before on this site -- but worded in a way that makes it hard to recognize as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your updated question sounds like something you would need to be extremely careful with but here y'go (I changed the sample input as I don't want to mess around with creating files in `/tmp`!):

```
$ cat file
#First Command
echo 'here is the date'
date +'%D'

#Second Command
echo 'here is the time'
date +'%T'              

$ IFS=$'\n' var=( $(awk -v RS= -v FS='\n' -v OFS=';' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}' file) )

$ echo "${var[0]}"
echo 'here is the date';date +'%D'

$ echo "${var[1]}"
echo 'here is the time';date +'%T'

$ eval "${var[0]}"          
here is the date
05/07/15

$ eval "${var[1]}"
here is the time
11:42:51
```

You can decide if `eval` or `declare` or something else is the right way to execute the command.

Comment: My apologies, I have added a clarification on what I'm actually looking to do. Using awk to section the information isn't the problem, but to make each section to be a variable that can be called at a later time. Does that make better sense, my apologies!

Comment: The groupings are lists of commands that I have simplified to words just for the simplicity of the question. to your last comment, yes, the file literally contains commands that need to be executed.

Comment: Wow, you are awesome. Thank you for understanding what I was actually asking when i was being so backwards in my asking. I really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It sounds like you're just starting to learn about shell so be extremely careful with `eval` (or `declare`), make sure you read up on it and can make a well informed decision before implementing this. You should also look at shell functions - some functions in your `ENV` file would probably be a much better option than the above.